# monaco-editor-webpack-plugin Create React App Build with react-router causing incorrect location for chunks

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, monaco-editor

Getting the below error, it should be: http://localhost:4000/webapp/static/js/328.f5f431ed.chunk.js

This only happens for production builds and not development running.

It is appending to the end of the react router route. Not sure how to configure this properly?

```
Uncaught (in promise) ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 328 failed.
(missing: http://localhost:4000/webapp/editor/ae2c222b-fc4b-40b7-bfae-7a0750c011fc/static/js/328.f5f431ed.chunk.js)
    at Object.__webpack_require__.f.j (jsonp chunk loading:27:18)
```

Tried to change the config - tried different combinations of this and can't get it to work.

craco.config.js

```js
const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    webpack: {
        output: {
            publicPath: '/webapp/',
          },
        plugins: [new MonacoWebpackPlugin({ publicPath: '/webapp/', languages: ['json', 'python', 'shell', 'python']})],
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure this out

In package.json instead of

```
"homepage": ".",
```

use:

```
"homepage": "/webapp/",
```

Comment: This is also mentioned at the end of the production build. Check the output after the file list.